# Get specific string from File Name in C#

Tags: c#

I have a directory with release note files, I need to show a link to their pdf in website:

File names look like this:

```
Appower Release Notes 2.104.0_August102021.pdf
Appower Release Notes 2.107.0_November092021.pdf
Appower Release Notes 2.108.0_December072021.pdf
```

HTML markup:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a download="" href="~/Content/ReleaseNotes/ Appower Release Notes 2.104.0_August102021.pdf">August</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a download="" href="~/Content/ReleaseNotes/Appower Release Notes 2.107.0_November092021.pdf">November</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a download="" href="~/Content/ReleaseNotes/Appower Release Notes 2.108.0_December072021.pdf">December</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Instead of hardcoding August, November and December, I need to get the month from File name, so Every time that I upload files I can get the name dynamically instead of code change,

I have tried to use this code:

```
var enumDir = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ReleaseNotes"))
                       .Where(a => Path.GetFileName(a).Length > 12);

foreach (var item in enumDir)
{
    var alt_right6 = new string(item.Reverse().Take(10).Reverse().ToArray()); 
}
```

This code will return this: `102021.pdf` - how get December from this?

Also open to better approach.

Comment: `string month = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("([^A-Z]*)([a-zA-Z]*)").Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item).Split('.').Last()).Groups[2].Value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use regular expressions here to find month's name in the file name:

```
string pattern = @"([a-zA-Z]+)\d+.pdf";  // finds a word with digits and .pdf in the end

  RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
 foreach (var item in enumDir)
        {
            var matches = Regex.Matches(item, pattern, options);
            var month = matches.FirstOrDefault()?.Groups[1].Value;
        }
```